# C# shortcut for a List property that should never return null

Tags: c#, accessor

In order to make sure that a list property would never return null, I declared it this way:

```
    private IList<Item> _myList;

    [NotNull]
    public IList<Item> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList ?? new List<Item>(); }
        set { _myList = value; }
    }
```

This works, but I hate the syntax. Considering that I should use this technique extensively throughout my project, I'm looking for a better way to write this or a better solution to the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: `private readonly IList<Item> _myList = new List<Item>()` this will ensure it is never null

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even if you initialize _myList as a new List, that doesn't mean that its value cannot be set to null afterwards.

Comment: @tocqueville true, it can only then be set in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the good way to do it but each time `MyList` is required and `_myList` is null, you will create a new empty List... So if `_myList` is empty and someone do `MyList.Add(item);` it will not be added to the right list.

Better do this :

```
private IList<Item> _myList;

[NotNull]
public IList<Item> MyList
{
    get { return _myList ?? (_myList = new List<Item>()); }
    set { _myList = value; }
}
```

That way, first time `_myList` is null, you create a new list. Then, `_myList` will not be null.

Comment: Good point about calling `.Add()` when the backing member is `null`.  The OP's code has a significant bug in that regard, as consuming code would have no idea that the list being used is immediately being discarded.  All the talk on other answers about "this would behave differently" seems to neglect that the current behavior is broken.

Comment: @tocqueville, yes sorry, fixed, I've forgot the () around the new List.

Comment: I tested it and it works. Very good point about the .Add() problem, I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: C# 8 introduced the Compound Assignment operator (??=) making this cleaner:
```
private IList<Item> _myList;

[NotNull]
public IList<Item> MyList
{
    get => _myList ??= new List<Item>();
    set =>  _myList = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of C# 6.0, you can initialize properties that use an auto-implemented field.  This will ensure that MyList is never a null value:

```
public IList<Item> MyList { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
```

Comment: See comments on Zohar Peled answer, this is very different from  my code

Answer (score 0):

> This works, but I hate the syntax.

I hate the idea that returning a new list and immediately dropping it is a good idea. I think you should try to think of other ways to solve this.

Does the returned value really be non-nullable? If so, create a proper instance instead of dropping it the moment you create it:

```
[NotNull]
public IList<Item> MyList
{
    get { return _myList ?? (_myList = new List<Item>()); }
    set { _myList = value; }
}
```

If you can life with a nullable list, you might just want to shorthand null-checking:

```
if (list?.Contains(...) ?? false)
{ }
```